# How to change referenced numpy arrays to a slice of itself?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

Consider the following operation and slicing applied to two numpy arrays:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                               

In [2]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4])                                                                          

In [3]: b = np.array([5,6,7,8])                                                                          

In [4]: a[2:] = 0                                                                                       

In [5]: a = a[::2]                                                                                       

In [6]: b[2:] = 0                                                                                       

In [7]: b = b[::2]                                                                                       

In [8]: a                                                                                                
Out[8]: array([1, 0])

In [9]: b                                                                                                
Out[9]: array([5, 0])
```

I do not want to repeat the slicing code, for example, instead of lines [4]-[7] above, I wish to use something like

```
In [4]: for data in [a,b] : 
   ...:     data[2:] = 0
   ...:     data = data[::2]
```

I understand that it does not work because the effect of `data = data[::2]` is to make `data` to point a new object, not to change the original objects. So the values of `a` and `b` are not sliced:

```
In [5]: a                                                                                                
Out[5]: array([1, 2, 0, 0])

In [6]: b                                                                                                
Out[6]: array([5, 6, 0, 0])
```

My question is:

How to slice a numpy array referenced by a variable?

In my real application, I an doing several operations in each array, and want to have them all in the same block inside the `for`.

Comment: I have updated my answer too. Check it out and see if it helps.

Comment: Are the ararys a and b the same size? Is it just 2 of them?

Comment: @yatu, they are not necessarilly of the same size and it may be several of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to map the slicing on all the variables

```py
import numpy as np                                                                               
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])                                                                          
b = np.array([5,6,7,8])

def func(x):
    x[2:] = 0
    x = x[::2] 
    return x
[a,b] = list(map(func,[a,b]))
print(a,b)
```

Output:

```
[1 0] [5 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. I should have mentioned that I do other operations in the arrays. I will correct the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Then just replace the `lambda` function with function that contains all the operations that you want to apply.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that lambda functions can describe every possible operation in an array. For example, how could it code the operation described in my question?

Comment: I have removed `lambda` and used a general function. You can add more operations in it if you want.

Comment: I had thought of a similar solution `[a,b] = [func(x) for x in [a,b]]`, but I don't like the repetition of the same list of arrays in two places.

Comment: Thanks @paradoxlover. I wonder if a simpler solution exists, without the need of defining a new function.

Comment: Well, time to put on the thinking cap. :wink:

Comment: You can directly unpack the generator, no need to assign into a list in the lhs.. so  `a,b = map(func,[a,b])`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a dictionary:

```
import numpy as np

arrs = {'a': np.array([1,2,3,4]), 'b': np.array([5,6,7,8])}
arrs = {k: v[::2] for k, v in arrs.items()}
print(arrs)
```

output:

```
{'a': array([1, 3]), 'b': array([5, 7])}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
a,b = [arr[::2] for arr in [a,b]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some confusion over creating array objects and assigning values.

Let me illustrate:

Define two arrays:

```
In [5]: a=np.arange(1,5); b=np.arange(5,10)
```

Make a list of those two arrays:

```
In [6]: alist = [a,b]
```

and a generic function that returns a new array (the fact that it's a view doesn't matter):

```
In [7]: def foo(i): 
   ...:     return i[2:] 
   ...:
```

The function could be applied to the array referenced by `a`:

```
In [8]: foo(a)                                                                  
Out[8]: array([3, 4])
```

or to each of the arrays referenced by `alist`:

```
In [9]: [foo(i) for i in alist]                                                 
Out[9]: [array([3, 4]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

those arrays could be unpacked to variables (new or old names):

```
In [10]: a,d = [foo(i) for i in alist]                                          
In [11]: a                                                                      
Out[11]: array([3, 4])          # the new sliced array
In [12]: b                                                                      
Out[12]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])    # the original array
In [13]: d                                                                      
Out[13]: array([7, 8, 9])           # a slice of b
```

the original arrays are still present in `alist`.  The fact that `a` has a new value does not change `alist`:

```
In [14]: alist                                                                  
Out[14]: [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

unpacked assignment via `map` does the same thing:

```
In [15]: d,e = map(foo, alist)                                                  
In [16]: d,e                                                                    
Out[16]: (array([3, 4]), array([7, 8, 9]))
```

Making a dictionary of the sliced arrays also works:

```
In [17]: {key: foo(value) for key, value in zip(['e','d'],alist)}               
Out[17]: {'e': array([3, 4]), 'd': array([7, 8, 9])}
```